# similar use of operator overloading in python functions

Tags: python

Is there a way to use variable like in operator overloading.
e.g.

```
a += 1
```

Instead of `a = a + 1`

in

```
a = max(a, some_other_variable)
```

The max() function is just an example.

---

NOTE:
My intent here is not to use the variable 'a' again, if possible. These two examples are different and not related to each other.
e.g.

```
a = some_function(a, b)
```

Here, the values returned from some_function() is assigned back to variable 'a' again.
Unless variable 'a' is a class variable I cannot access variable inside function some_function(), although if there is a way so that I can use it only once?

Comment: I'm confused.  what do you want to do?  could you clarify?

Comment: Most likely something like `a max= 1`, which would hypothetically have an effect like `a = max(a, 1)`. I've frequently wished the language was expressive enough to permit such constructs, though `max`ing over a list or genexp is frequently a good replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot supplement Python's set of operators and statements directly in the Python code. However, you can write a wrapper that uses Python's [language services](http://docs.python.org/2/library/language.html) to write a Pythonesque DSL which includes the operators you want.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you want something along these lines ...

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __iadd__(self, other):
...         return max(self.num, other)
...     def __init__(self, num):
...         self.num = num
... 
>>> a = Foo(5)
>>> a += 4
>>> print a
5
>>> a = Foo(4)
>>> a += 6
>>> a
6
```

But please note that I would consider this use of `__iadd__` to be very impolite.  Having `__iadd__` return something other than `self` is generally inconsiderate if the type is mutable.

Comment: But this will have the same problem of using `a` twice, because you'll need to re-declare it (if it already was declared) in order to make this new type...

Comment: @JBernardo -- I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you suggesting I remove the `max` function in favor of something like `self if self.num > other else other`?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that if the original problem was "typing `a` twice", you will sustain the problem except in cases where `a` wasn't already declared. `a = Foo(a); a += b` -> see, `Foo(a)` is the same problem as `max(a, b)`

Comment: I think I'm going to institute a new person policy -- If people start commenting on my answer saying "I think that OP really wanted to do ..." and then I re-read the post and still don't understand it, I'm going to start voting to close as "unclear what you're asking" ;-)

Comment: I posted an answer based on his comment which seems to have more information than the confusing question

Comment: Oh, both users are named `userNNNNN`... I should read the numbers more carefully

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overloading an operator in `a` like the other answer, you could create a partial-like object for the second part. (I used the left shift operator for "coolness")

```
class partial(functools.partial):
    def __rlshift__(self, val):
        return self(val)
```

and use like this:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> a <<= partial(max, 20)
>>> a
20
```

So you don't need to mess with your variable types to execute the operation. Also you will not need to declare a new class for every function.

PS: Beware that the actual execution is `max(20, a)`.